# IOS - get a value from a table view controller and send it to another table view controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview

I have two Table View Controller in a Navigation Controller. The Cloth table is the main view and when I click on one of the cells go to another view controller that gives me the detail, when I select the option i want and return to the Return of the Navigation button, I lose the information. How do I take the value to the main view?

Here my code: Main View - AddClothViewController

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if ([[list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Categorias"] )
{

    CategoriesViewController *DVC = [[CategoriesViewController alloc]    initWithNibName:@"CategoriesViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:DVC animated:YES];
}

}
```

Here my code: Categories ViewController

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// Set the checkmark accessory for the selected row.
[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]  setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];

// This is my main View Controller when i declare a variable category and I try to access   from 
 //here    
  AddClothViewController *DVC = [[AddClothViewController alloc]  initWithNibName:@"AddClothViewController" bundle:nil];
  DVC.clothNew.categoria = [list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ];
```

}

Comment: You're creating a new instance of AddClothViewController, not going back to the one you came from.

Comment: Yeah you right!!. But I don't know how i get the value, when i press the back button. Do you have an example? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem by using this [tutorial](http://www.hardcodedstudios.com/home/ryan-newsome/simpledelegatetutorialforiosdevelopment).
(Simple delegate tutorial for ios development)